# IOS/Storyboard/Autolayout: Right side of elements getting clipped on Iphone 7 Plus

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I am applying Autolayout to some textfields and they are getting clipped off on the right as shown here.

[image]

The View controller width is 375 as per docs.  The upper textfield has a leading and trailing margin of 20.  The trailing constraint reads:
View.trailing = Text Field.trailing Constant 20, Priority 1000, Multiplier 1.  Relative to margin is unchecked both in view.trailing and textfield.trailing

So I'm stumped on what could be causing it to get clipped on the larger phone.  (It shows fine on an Iphone 6).

Here is full set of constraints in storyboard.

[[image]]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you upload code to GitHub and share the same link, it will be much easier to solve.

Comment: I don't see any constraints for your scroll view? And your Text Field is a subview of your scroll view, but you have it constrained to the `View`?

Comment: Ok.  Perhaps I should be constraining everything to the scrollview.

Comment: Is it necessary (or at least advised) to put everything in a scrollview inside one Content View child container as this article suggests?   https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: Constraining the scrollview to the view on all four sides solved the clipping problem.  Thx!